# How to edit a custom webpart in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-parts

I would like to know how to edit the webpart as it has a typo.

I'm unable to find the html in SharePoint Designer and I could only find the aspx file for the page under Pages. When I check the page out, I cannot edit the webpart directly. Is there a html page I can download from the Site Contents.